# How to call a method to get area of a triangle

Tags: c#, methods

This is the code I have but I do not know which keyword to use to link my main code up to the method. Any help?

```
try
{
    double numA = Convert.ToInt32(tbx1.Text);
    double numB = Convert.ToInt32(tbx2.Text);
    double numC = Convert.ToInt32(tbx3.Text);

    double area;

    area = (numA + numB + numC) / 2;

    tblk1.Text = area.ToString();
}
catch (FormatException fE)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input must be in text format");
}
catch (Exception eX)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Number is negative!");
}

public void area(double area)
{
    area = (numA + numB + numC) / 2;
    return area;
}
```

Comment: As a side note look at int.TryParse instead of Convert and catching errors

Comment: downvoters please comment to help out new users

Comment: Ok thanks I will look into it but I'm currently using convert the whole time, is that a bad thing?

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/determining-a-triangles-area-from-its-base-and-hei.html

Comment: @user3204290 it's generally good practice to try and check if there will be an issue rather than checking if there was one

Comment: @user3204290 a final note - you may want to consider using a decimal for your lengths - what if your edge is 1.5 long?

Comment: Oh yeah I will actually change this around, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a `double` for your `area()` function, not `void`. You also need a different parameter list:

```
public double area(double height, double length, double width)
{
    area = (height * length * width) / 2;
    return area;
}
```

---

Edit, this should probably be more appropriately named volume, but here you go for both:

```
public double area(double length, double width)
{
    var x = (length * width);
    return x;
}

public double volume(double height, double length, double width)
{
    var x = (height * length * width);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: because you are trying to assign the return value to a variable

Comment: @user3204290 it can't be `void` because you `return` value :-)

Comment: My maths is a little rusty but shouldn't there be a multiply in there somewhere?

Comment: I think that the Area of a triangle is (Base * Height) / 2(Deriving from the Area formula of a rectangle)

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I appreciate your comments and I'm learning from them :)

Comment: This is what I found for the area but didn't know what the S meant so I just used another one instead. My maths is bad. Math.Sqrt(s * (s – a) * (s – b) * (s – c));

Comment: The Base for a triangle is easy, but the height has to be calculated.(It is the line that lands perpendicular to the base from the opposing angle)

Comment: for triangle, use area function for square and divide by 2, using base and height as parameters

Comment: @BlackICE It is a bit complicated, because there are many types of triangles.

Comment: Ok I will mess around with that formula for awhile, thanks @BlackIce and everyone else!

Comment: @ThunderGr yes, mine was specifically for right triangles, for others you have to calculate height (or base)

Comment: @BlackICE Just for accuracy, the Base is any side of the triangle you select. The height must be calculated, in respect to chosen base. On Right Triangles, of course, trying to calculate a Height by taking the hypotenuse of the triangle as a Base is a waste of time :).

Comment: @user3204290 S is half the perimeter of the triangle. This is (a+b+c)/2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try
{
    double numA = Convert.ToInt32(tbx1.Text); 
    double numB = Convert.ToInt32(tbx2.Text);
    double numC = Convert.ToInt32(tbx3.Text);

    tblk1.Text = area(numA, numB, numC).ToString();
}
catch (FormatException fE)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input must be in text format");
}
catch (Exception eX)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Number is negative!");
}

public double area(int numA, int numB, int numC)
{
    area = (numA + numB + numC) / 2;
    return area;
}
```